# Getting object key by 'indexof' value of dropdown

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have 2 dropdowns, one which allows you to select the 'Brand' and 2nd which allows you to select the 'parameter' to get to the respective 'SubBrands' within the 'Brand' selected.

My Array:

```
var Brand = { "Brand1-Parameter1-SubBrand1": [{"Image": "animal", "Heading": "SubBrand1", "Link": "SubBrand1"}], 
                "Brand1-Parameter1-SubBrand2": [{ "Image": "animal", "Heading": "SubBrand2", "Link": "SubBrand2"}], 
                "Brand1-Parameter2-SubBrand3": [{ "Image": "water", "Heading": "SubBrand3", "Link": "SubBrand3" }], 
                "Brand1-Parameter2-SubBrand4": [{ "Image": "water", "Heading": "SubBrand4", "Link": "SubBrand4" }], 
                "Brand2-Parameter1-SubBrand5": [{ "Image": "travel", "Heading": "SubBrand5", "Link": "SubBrand5" }], 
                "Brand2-Parameter1-SubBrand6": [{ "Image": "travel", "Heading": "SubBrand6", "Link": "SubBrand6" }], 
                "Brand2-Parameter2-SubBrand7": [{ "Image": "flower", "Heading": "SubBrand7", "Link": "SubBrand7" }], 
                "Brand2-Parameter2-SubBrand8": [{ "Image": "flower", "Heading": "SubBrand8", "Link": "SubBrand8" }], 
            }
```

My first jquery filters the array for the 'Brand' selected in the dropdown, which works:

```
$("#ParentBrand").on('change', function() {
    var ParentBrandSelected = $('#ParentBrand').val();
    var ParentBrandKeys = Object.keys(Brand).filter(v => v.startsWith(ParentBrandSelected))
```

The second part of this should filter the keys containing 'Parameters' selected with 'indexOf'.

```
$("#Parameter").on('change', function() {
        var ParameterSelected = $('#Parameter').val()
        var ParentBrandParameterKeys = ParentBrandKeys.map(key => Object.keys(Brand[key]).filter(v => v.indexOf(ParameterSelected) > -1))
```

However this second part doesn't work and the console shows an empty array. How do I filter the Object Keys containing the selected parameters?

Find full code below:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var Brand = {
    "Brand1-Parameter1-SubBrand1": [{
      "Image": "animal",
      "Heading": "SubBrand1",
      "Link": "SubBrand1"
    }],
    "Brand1-Parameter1-SubBrand2": [{
      "Image": "animal",
      "Heading": "SubBrand2",
      "Link": "SubBrand2"
    }],
    "Brand1-Parameter2-SubBrand3": [{
      "Image": "water",
      "Heading": "SubBrand3",
      "Link": "SubBrand3"
    }],
    "Brand1-Parameter2-SubBrand4": [{
      "Image": "water",
      "Heading": "SubBrand4",
      "Link": "SubBrand4"
    }],
    "Brand2-Parameter1-SubBrand5": [{
      "Image": "travel",
      "Heading": "SubBrand5",
      "Link": "SubBrand5"
    }],
    "Brand2-Parameter1-SubBrand6": [{
      "Image": "travel",
      "Heading": "SubBrand6",
      "Link": "SubBrand6"
    }],
    "Brand2-Parameter2-SubBrand7": [{
      "Image": "flower",
      "Heading": "SubBrand7",
      "Link": "SubBrand7"
    }],
    "Brand2-Parameter2-SubBrand8": [{
      "Image": "flower",
      "Heading": "SubBrand8",
      "Link": "SubBrand8"
    }],
  }

  $("#ParentBrand").on('change', function() {
    var ParentBrandSelected = $('#ParentBrand').val();
    var ParentBrandKeys = Object.keys(Brand).filter(v => v.startsWith(ParentBrandSelected))
    console.log(ParentBrandSelected, ParentBrandKeys)
    jQuery("#Parameter").val(null).trigger('change');

    $("#Parameter").on('change', function() {
      var ParameterSelected = $('#Parameter').val()
      var ParentBrandParameterKeys = ParentBrandKeys.map(key => Object.keys(Brand[key]).filter(v => v.indexOf(ParameterSelected) > -1))
      console.log(ParentBrandParameterKeys)
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>Select the Brand:
    <select id="ParentBrand">
      <option></option>
      <option value="Brand1">Brand1</option>
      <option value="Brand2">Brand2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>Select the Parameter:
    <select id="Parameter">
      <option></option>
      <option value="Parameter1">Parameter1</option>
      <option value="Parameter2">Parameter2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a boolean result so `indexOf`isn't the best tool for the job. `includes` is preferred unless you actually need the index.

Your logic was failing because you were trying to reference the `ParentBrandKeys` array in your second pulldown - but it was scoped to it's own function, and so empty to your logic.

If you make the 2 values global variables, you can utilize them in each others logic. For example once you select the brand, you can use that as a filter on the parameters.  In this, we save the variables outside of the functions and test for them using:

```
 v.split("-").includes(ParentBrandSelected) && v.split("-").includes(ParameterSelected)
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var Brand = {
    "Brand1-Parameter1-SubBrand1": [{
      "Image": "animal",
      "Heading": "SubBrand1",
      "Link": "SubBrand1"
    }],
    "Brand1-Parameter1-SubBrand2": [{
      "Image": "animal",
      "Heading": "SubBrand2",
      "Link": "SubBrand2"
    }],
    "Brand1-Parameter2-SubBrand3": [{
      "Image": "water",
      "Heading": "SubBrand3",
      "Link": "SubBrand3"
    }],
    "Brand1-Parameter2-SubBrand4": [{
      "Image": "water",
      "Heading": "SubBrand4",
      "Link": "SubBrand4"
    }],
    "Brand2-Parameter1-SubBrand5": [{
      "Image": "travel",
      "Heading": "SubBrand5",
      "Link": "SubBrand5"
    }],
    "Brand2-Parameter1-SubBrand6": [{
      "Image": "travel",
      "Heading": "SubBrand6",
      "Link": "SubBrand6"
    }],
    "Brand2-Parameter2-SubBrand7": [{
      "Image": "flower",
      "Heading": "SubBrand7",
      "Link": "SubBrand7"
    }],
    "Brand2-Parameter2-SubBrand8": [{
      "Image": "flower",
      "Heading": "SubBrand8",
      "Link": "SubBrand8"
    }],
  }

  let ParentBrandSelected = '',
    ParameterSelected = ''
  $("#ParentBrand").on('change', function() {
    ParentBrandSelected = $(this).val();
    let ParentBrandKeys = Object.keys(Brand).filter(v => v.startsWith(ParentBrandSelected))
    console.log(ParentBrandSelected, ParentBrandKeys)
    jQuery("#Parameter").val(null).trigger('change');

    $("#Parameter").on('change', function() {
      ParameterSelected = $(this).val()
      let ParentBrandParameterKeys = Object.keys(Brand).filter(v => v.split("-").includes(ParentBrandSelected) && v.split("-").includes(ParameterSelected))
      console.log(ParentBrandParameterKeys)

      let markup = ''
      jQuery.each(ParentBrandParameterKeys, function(index, value) {
        let useValue = Brand[value][0]
        markup += '<a href="/Directory/SubDirectory/' + useValue.Link + '.html">'
        markup += '<div class="InnerBlock">'
        markup += '<div style="background-image:url(https://source.unsplash.com/1280x720/?' + useValue.Image + ')">' + useValue.Heading + '</div>'
        markup += '</div>'
        markup += '</a>'
      });

      console.log(markup)


    });
  });



});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>Select the Brand:
    <select id="ParentBrand">
      <option></option>
      <option value="Brand1">Brand1</option>
      <option value="Brand2">Brand2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>Select the Parameter:
    <select id="Parameter">
      <option></option>
      <option value="Parameter1">Parameter1</option>
      <option value="Parameter2">Parameter2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In continuation to the above, if I wish to use the values of each of the keys `jQuery.each(ParentBrandParameterKeys, function(index, value){markup += '<a href="/Directory/SubDirectory/'+ value.Link +'.html">'markup += '<div class="InnerBlock">'markup += '<div style="background-image:url(https://source.unsplash.com/1280x720/?' + value.Image +')">'+ value.Heading +'</div>'markup += '</div>'markup += '</a>'});'` doesnt work. How do I get each value from this? SOrry for the silly questions, I'm still learning this.

Comment: I updated my answer to show how. The array is an array of KEYS so you'll need to access the `Brand` object to find which data to use. Then, in `Brand` the data is in an array, so you find the object like `useValue = Brand[value][0]` - see updated